# Upload image from Android client to Salesforce Custom Object

Tags: java, android, salesforce

I am developing Android application which requires salesforce integration.

As per current requirement i want to upload image file from Android application to salesforce custom object. I am able to post other data to custom object (i.e other then image files) using salesforce REST API - but i do not find any option in salesforce API which supports file upload operation(multi-part upload) from client/Android.

Is there any other way to post file/image data to salesforce.com and store to custom object?

Any help/pointer on this - greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

From @superfell's blog:

> In the recent Spring release (v24) ... you can now work with binary data (blobs in apex) directly in the http request or response. Here's an example of making a HTTP GET request for an image PNG file, and saving it to the document object in salesforce.

This is how you use save binary data to a document in force.com. You can link that document to the custom object.

```
HttpRequest r = new HttpRequest();
r.setMethod('GET');
r.setEndpoint('http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/soqlxicon.png');
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(r);
blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();

Document d = new Document();
d.name = 'logo.png';
d.body = image;
d.folderId = UserInfo.getUserId();
insert d;
system.debug(d.id);
```

Otherwise, you can save the base64 encoded version of the image in a long text field on the custom object.

Comment: Thanks Sean Devine, thanks for code and pointers - will try and let you know thanks. (One Question: Do i need to use SDK?, i think no)

Comment: You don't need to use an SDK. I'm not sure about what you're doing exactly, but feel free to post a follow up to this if you have trouble after you've read the documentation and given it a shot.

Comment: Thanks again, sure will check and go through documentations and try 

Just  FYR: I am developing one simple Android application which captures image from android application and then i want to upload this captured image to salesforce.com custom field (i.e of custom object). 

Data type of this custom field is Rich Text Area", may be uploading base64 image data to "Rich Text Area" of custom object should work - will check and let you know, If you have specific pointer/comment on the basis of above requirement please let me know - thx!

Comment: Hi Sean Devine, I have referred this link: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/converting-a-rich-text-area-fields-image-for-api-upload

I have tried base64 stuff and as per current implementation i am getting erro: Invalid encoding specified:  base64. The base64 is the only supported encoding.","errorCode":"INVALID_DATA_URI"

I am using API v20.0

Comment: Android Code:
// Here 'imgBytes' object is nothing but compressed image data
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Put base64 image data with image tag in JSON object parameter
data.put("Meter_Reading_Picture__c", "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg; base64," + encodedImage + "></img>");

// ....
post.setHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + myTokens.get_access_token());
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");